# Excel Conditional data selection by formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Stuck on looks-easy task. I have a table like that:
AAAA    spoon 
BBBB    fork 
CCCC    stick 
BBBB    digger 
AAAA    apple 
BBBB    nail 
AAAA    cap 
CCCC    watermelon  
CCCC    banana 
BBBB    slush 
AAAA    pie 
CCCC    tin-plate 
AAAA    raspberries

And need to select only "AAAA" values to another table:
spoon
apple
cap
pie
raspberries
An need to do it dinamically by means of formula, so it will updates each time first table updates. It is not so difficult with VBA, but need formula.

Comment: yep. this thing works fine, array is not a problem. but result is not only required cells but and a lot of empty ones "". I need only selected values without gaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed that your entries where in two columns. For this equation I put them in B and C starting at row 2. I used F1 to enter the string you want to sort by.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$14, SMALL(IF($F$1=$B$2:$B$14, ROW($B$2:$B$14)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$14))+1, ""), ROW(C1))), "")
```

You have to paste this equation in as many rows as the number of answers you expect. If you expect 20 results paste this into 20 rows and the last `ROW(C1)` should auto increment. The `IFERROR` keeps the cell blank if no match is included.

Also after entering the equation you have to do `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks a lot!